# abstract method used without implementation

Tags: java, android, android-room

I was learning the Room Database for Android app development through a tutorial and came across an abstract method being used without its implementation. Following are the files:

1. AppDatabase.java

   ```
   @Database(entities = {Contact.class}, version = 1)
   public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
       private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
       private static AppDatabase database;

       **public abstract ContactDao getContactDao();**

       public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
       if(database == null)
       {
           database = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
               .allowMainThreadQueries().build();
       }
       return database;
     }
   }
   ```

The method getContactDao is being used in another file:

2. ContactsFragment

   ```
   public class ContactsFragment extends Fragment {

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);

   AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(getContext());
   **ContactDao contactoDao = database.getContactDao();**
   return view;
   }
   }
   ```

Here is the ContactDao class:

```
    public interface ContactDao {

        @Query("SELECT * FROM contact")
        List<Contact> getAll();

        @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
        void insert(Contact contact);

        @Update
        void update(Contact contact);

        @Delete
        void delete(Contact contact);

    }
```

My question is what does the getContactDao method do? And shouldn't the abstract class be implemented before being used?

Comment: It is implemented. The `getInstance` method returns an implementation.

Comment: Oh okay. Is there any way that I can see it? And what does it do exactly?

Comment: @Jim can you CTRL+click on it? (in Eclipse, I don't know Android studio well)

Comment: @GregT Hi! Yes. I can see the getInstance implementation but not the getContactDao().

Comment: Try printing `database.getClass().getName()` too see which implementation it is .

Comment: Jim as @RealSkeptic pointed out, it has to be somewhere the getInstance implementation (or wherever the object returned by getInstance is created)

Comment: I searched the whole project, but could not find the implementation of it. The only two places where "getContactDao()" are used are the declaration part and the use (as above).

Comment: Did you try @Berger's idea? Could you post `getInstance()` and also the constructor of whatever it returns?

Comment: Actually, there is an implementation present in the generated files of AppDatabase when I run the app. I guess it is auto generated.

Comment: @GregT Yes I put a breakpoint and checked. It gave me "AppDatabase_Impl.java". Says it is a generated file and should not be edited". Looked into it and there is an implementation.